Select specific version present in ld version script
Consider the setup present in this question:
GNU LD symbol versioning & C++ binary backwards-compatibility
Consider the version script. Is it possible to explicitly tell ld to limit the exposed symbols to a specific version?
In this case, what I would like to do is to expose only the symbols associated to LIB_0 and ignore LIB_1 .
